# Is it true that we can always select two rows which are dependent on another in a singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question with a singular matrix.

I know, 'the matrix A is a singular matrix' means 'the matrix A doesn't have an inverse matrix' and "Row vectors in an invertible matrix are independent with others."

So, is it true that "Some row vectors in a singular matrix have other dependent row vectors?"

Sorry for my English skill. ;)

I want to know,
"We can always select two row vectors which are dependent on another in a singular matrix." and "We can always select a vector which is independent with all respective row vectors in a singular matrix.(a selected vector is not a row vector of that matrix)"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If a square matrix is singular, then some row vector is a linear combination of others. (But some other row vectors may NOT be linear combinations)

Details: I'm going to prove the corresponding statments about columns.

Since the matrix is not invertible, there are two distinct vectors $v$ and $w$ with $Mv = Mw$, so $M(v-w) = 0$. So $u = v-w$ is a nonzero vector with $Mu = 0$.

Writing the columns of $M$ as $M_i$, we can restate this as

$$
u_1 M_1 + u_2 M_2 + \ldots u_n M_n = 0
$$
where not all $u_i$ are zero. Well, suppose that $u_1$ is not zero; then 
$$
M_1 = - (\frac{u_2}{u_1} M_2 + \ldots + \frac{u_n}{u_1} M_n).
$$

The last statement you made, rewritten to be a little clearer in English, seems to be

"In any singular matrix, there is some row that is *not* expressible as a linear combination of the remaining rows." That statement is false, as the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
shows.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and I'm sorry that my question is too ambiguous to understand. So, I decide to upload a new question related with this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer according to as far as I have understood you question.

For your 1st question:

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 &1 &  0\end{bmatrix}$ is singular but $R_i \ne \alpha R_j \forall \alpha \in \mathbb R \forall i,j \in \{1,2,3\} and i\ne j $ where $R_i$ denotes ith row.

For your 2nd question:

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 &0 &  1\end{bmatrix}$ is singular but 3rd row is not a linear combination of other rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I'm so sorry that my question is too vague. I want to know, "Is there a orthogonal vector **x** with R_i?"(R_i is ith row vector of a singular matrix.)